# how to use two mysql instances with saltstack and mysql-formula

Tags: mysql, salt-stack

I'm trying to use mysql-formula and I'm not quite grokking how it is expected to work.

In particular, it's apparently not possible to refer to two mysql configurations at once.  This question is in the hope that I've missed something.

I have two mysql instances.

### salt/top.sls

```
base:
  'db1-host':
    - MySQL
  'db2-host':
    - MySQL
```

### pillar/top.sls

```
base:
  'db1-host':
    - mysql.db1-host
  'db2-host':
    - mysql.db2-host
```

And then there are files `salt/MySQL/init.sls`, `pillar/mysql/db1-host.sls`, and `pillar/mysql/db2-host.sls`.

But now what happens when I have some applications that want to use these databases?  They need to know credentials.  Easy enough,

### salt/top.sls

```
base:
  'db1-host':
    - mysql
  'db2-host':
    - MySQL
  'app1-host':
    - app
  'app2-host':
    - app
```

### pillar/top.sls

```
base:
  'db1-host':
    - mysql.db1-host
  'db2-host':
    - mysql.db2-host
  'app1-host':
    - mysql.db1-host
  'app2-host':
    - mysql.db2-host
```

Good enough.  But it turns out that the applications are lightweight enough to run on one host.

### salt/top.sls

```
base:
  'db1-host':
    - mysql
  'db2-host':
    - MySQL
  'app-host':
    - app
```

And here I'm in trouble, because `pillar/mysql/db1-host` and `pillar/mysql/db2-host` have the same key names, just different values.  That's what mysql-formula wants.  So it's no longer clear how to write the app state file so that it picks out credentials for the two separate apps.

I see that there's now a [mysql module](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/modules/all/salt.modules.mysql.html) and a [mysql state](https://docs.saltstack.com/en/latest/ref/states/all/salt.states.mysql_database.html).  The docs are a bit unclear on what the intended distinction is, or whether one is intended to supplant the others.  Initially, the state looks promising but incomplete for fully managing mysql databases (e.g., the `/etc/mysql/my.cnf` contents, which I could control as a managed file), the module looks like it is meant for doing maintenance rather than assuring state.